# Looking to scale along normals using geometry nodes using a texture as a scaling factor

Tags: geometry-nodes, transforms, normals, mathematics, height-map

Not sure how feasable this would be but as the title suggests, I'm looking for a way to shrink a mesh along the vertex normals using a height map for the scaling factor.

Context: This is for an animal that was modelled initially without having fur taken into consideration... meaning that to add fur and still retain its overall shape / silhouette, the body underneath needs to shink based on a fur length map, where black is the original vertex position and white is the full length of the fur and shrunk.

In simpler terms; I need to de-fur a persian cat, and turn it into a sphynx cat! ¦D

I suppose it would need to apply the translation at the vertices, so as not to cause gaps in the mesh at different heights... but I'm struggling to figure out something that works.